# How can I prevent end of file errors that occur in the AWS EKS when communicating over an AWS NLB and rolling EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, nlb

I am running an AWS EKS cluster with EC2 instances in an autoscaling group (ASG) and using an upstream AWS Network Load Balancer (NLB) to access services in the cluster from outside AWS. However, during rolling updates of the ASG triggered e. g. by an AMI change, I am receiving numerous "end of file" errors when calling services in the cluster. We can see that 99% of the resets are coming from target  by checking TCP_Target_Reset_Count metric of the NLB.

Version of the Nginx Ingress in the cluster is: http://eu.gcr.io/k8s-artifacts-prod/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.5.2

I also checked the logs of the Nginx ingress controller of the cluster during the tests and found several error messages. However, I am not sure whether NLB health checks or our tests caused these errors. The messages appear frequently in the logs:

`Line 123: "33806 broken header: "" while reading PROXY protocol, client: 192.168.22.19, server: 0.0.0.0:443"`

`Line 151: "33794 client closed connection while SSL handshaking, client: 192.168.21.227, server: 0.0.0.0:443"`

I would appreciate any insights or advice on what could be causing the "end of file" errors during rolling updates when using the NLB and how to resolve this issue.

Interestingly, when I replace the NLB with an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB), I do not experience these errors during rolling updates. Another user gave a hint that the difference between NLB and the old CLB may be related to the parameter "Idle timeout."

I followed the suggestion and set the idle timeout on the old CLB to 350 seconds (as its the fixed value in NLB settings) and updated the setup to use the CLB instead of the NLB. However, the behavior did not change, and I continued to experience no "end of file" issues when using the CLB and rolling the cluster, while I continued to have them for several minutes when using the NLB and rolling the cluster.